# Is there any limitation for working on Java instead of C++ with ros, Morse or Blender?

Tags: ros, c++, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Am going to work on semantic description with Morse simulated area, The ROS will be used as a communication medium  between my semantic system and Morse system, I want to work with  java instead of C++ , so i want to know if there is there any limitation for working on Java instead of C++  with ros, Morse or Blender ?
If you can provide me some source of information, tutorials , I will really appreciated it.
Kind regard,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202321/is-there-any-limitation-for-working-on-java-instead-of-c++--with-ros,-morse-or-blender-?/) by [Nazeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21555/nazeer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-03**:
Perhaps you could elaborate a bit on what you mean with 'limitation'? Rosjava is pretty complete, feature wise, but it can be involved to setup and get into.

**Comment by [Nazeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21555/nazeer/) on 2015-02-05**:
I have never worked with ROS before now I have a big project using ros and semantic description i want to use java instead of C++, I know that C++ is fully supported with ros, so I want to make sure that Java also can do exactly what C++ does, that is what i meant by limitation ,thanks for reply,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosspp is one of the two major platforms officially supported by OSRF, while rosjava is externally maintained. While it has most important features, updates for a new platform may be delayed (e.g. there are no Indigo .deb packages yet). An important part that is missing is the actionlib implementation. There has been one for an earlier (incompatible) version of rosjava, but AFAIK it has not been ported yet.

Another issue is the rather shallow integration between the catkin buildsystem in ROS and the gradle buildsystem used for rosjava. This is no big deal if you are mostly working in the Java world and only interact with pre-compiled other ROS packages. If you have several ROS packages with rosjava code in your workspace, compilation can however become quite slow, and if you need to do some buildsystem magic, this may be limiting.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1